# largest to smallest: $\binom{n}{k}, \frac{n^k}{k!}, (\frac{n}{k})^k, (\frac{en}{k})^k$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

If $k$ and $n$ are both integers and $2\leq k \leq n$, what is the order of the  following quantities (smallest to largest): $\binom{n}{k}, \frac{n^k}{k!}, (\frac{n}{k})^k, (\frac{en}{k})^k$

Comment: What have you tried? (You can evaluate each of these for small values of $n$ and $k$ which will narrow down the possibilities.)

Comment: I know that $(\frac{en}{k})^k$ is larger than $(\frac{n}{k})^k$ because the numerator is multiplied by a constant factor.

Comment: Yes, that's right. What else? Remember that ${n \choose k} = \frac{n(n-1) \dots (n-k+1)}{k!}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to think through the definitions of exponential functions and factorials.

$k^k$ is the product of $k$ terms, all of which are $k$.

$k!$ is the product of $k$ terms, all of which are $\leq k$.

Therefore, $k!\leq k^k$.

Repeat this exercise for your numerators, and you will arrive at the answer.

Edit. If it's not immediately clear what the solution is when treating numerators and denominators separately, try to consider them together.

$\left(\frac{e n}{k}\right)^k$ is a product of $k$ terms, all of which are $\frac{e n}{k}$.

$\frac{n^k}{k!}$ is a product of $k$ terms, which are $\frac{n}{1},\frac{n}{2},\frac{n}{3},...$.

Suppose $k=2$. $\frac{e}{2}>1$ and $\frac{e}{2}>\frac{1}{2}$. For all terms here, $\left(\frac{e}{k}\right)^k>\frac{1}{k!}$ and therefore $\left(\frac{e n}{k}\right)^k>\frac{n^k}{k!}$.

Suppose $k=3$. $\frac{e}{3}<1$ but $\frac{e}{3}>\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{e}{3}>\frac{1}{3}$. For most terms, $\left(\frac{e}{k}\right)^k>\frac{1}{k!}$ and therefore $\left(\frac{e n}{k}\right)^k>\frac{n^k}{k!}$.

Suppose $k=4$. $\frac{e}{4}<1$ but $\frac{e}{4}>\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{e}{4}>\frac{1}{3}$ and $\frac{e}{4}>\frac{1}{4}$. For most terms, $\left(\frac{e}{k}\right)^k>\frac{1}{k!}$ and therefore $\left(\frac{e n}{k}\right)^k>\frac{n^k}{k!}$.

The pattern will continue to agree with $\left(\frac{e n}{k}\right)^k>\frac{n^k}{k!}$.

Comment: So would the solution (from smallest to largest) be: $(\frac{n}{k})^k, (\frac{en}{k})^k, \binom{n}{k}, \frac{n^k}{k!}$?

Comment: For the most part. I provided some further clarification on how we may compare $\left(\frac{e n}{k}\right)^k$ with the other terms.